# Updating second select option by php+ajax in a html table where adding new rows by javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

[image: Image which is showing totally what i'm trying to do..]

In this image i'm adding rows with that button by javascript code:

```
function addRow(dataTable) {
    "use strict";
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 100) {
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }   
     } else {
        alert("En fazla 100 satır ekleyebilirsiniz.");
    }
}
```

And also i'm changing option values of second select by these codes:

```
function fetch_select(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'stoklari_cek.php',
        data: {get_option:val},
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("sth_stok_kod").innerHTML=response; 
        }
    });
}
```

On first row of table I'm retrieving second options' values by changing first select. What i need to do is to make it workable in other rows too when i add with Add Row button. I mean when i add second row into the table and change the first select option value, FIRST ROW's SECOND SELECT OPTION VALUES are changing. 
But i need second rows second select options' values to be changed.

Comment: `document.getElementById("sth_stok_kod")` will always return the first element found and in your case it is the **first row's second select option**. Hence the reason it is always changing the first row's second select option.

Comment: That's what i thought too and that's the point i need help about,connecting  second javascript codes with the first one to change second selects values.

Comment: If I am hearing you correctly, you are saying you want to change the **second row second option** by changing the **first row first select** list?

Comment: As you see in the image there are three rows in the table. When i change first rows first select, first rows second select should be changed. Also if i change second rows first select , second rows second select should change. As a small information, in every rows first select i retrieve products groups names. In second selects i get the products names.

Comment: I get you now. Since you are dynamically creating the rows I suspect the **id** of the first row in all the rows is the same. It is for this reason that changing any other first select only affects **first row's second select** because it is the first element returned by `document.getElementById("sth_stok_kod")`.

Comment: Exactly that's my problem which i can't fix. I need to find a way to give unique id for every rows second select option and specify them in second javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your addRow function to the following. The idea here is to ensure that every row you create will have unique id's for the dropdown lists (selects).

```
function addRow(dataTable) {
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 100) {
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var newrow = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true); // clone the first row
        var selects = newrow.getElementsByTagName('select'); // get all selects in row
        for(var i=0; i<selects.length;i++) {
            selects[i].id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2); // generate random id's
        }
        table.appendChild(newrow);   
     } else {
        alert("En fazla 100 satır ekleyebilirsiniz.");
    }
}
```

In your function where you call `fetch_select` you will have to get the **id** of the **second select** you wish to change. You will then have to pass this **id** as an argument in `fetch_select`. Therefore, your `fetch_select` will also have to change to something like this.

```
function fetch_select(val, select_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'stoklari_cek.php',
        data: {get_option:val},
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById(select_id).innerHTML=response; 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: With your codes i can't retrieve values to the second selects. Seems like not reading stoklari_cek.php page or second javascripts onclick event is not working. These are my two selects in design.

Comment: Any idea why i can not retrieve values of second selects in every row of table according to your answer?